# HTML/CSS/JavaScript: Can't click slideshow indicator button

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm new to webpage design and am trying to add indicator dots on my slideshow, so when clicking on them, i can go to the next image.
[see this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C73xO.png) 
[image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yzT7h.png)

I initially followed the instructions on the W3School page: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_slideshow.asp
which put the indicator dots under the  tag and below the slideshow banner. However, I want to put the dots ON the slideshow banner so I changed the  tag to , but then the JavaScript stopped working.

In short, what I'm looking for is like the "another example" slideshow banner on this page: https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/w3css_slideshow.asp
sadly, the code used on that page was incomplete and i can't directly copy and paste it onto my website.

Please help to see what's wrong with my code OR to save your time, simply let me know how to achieve the feature mentioned in the above paragraph. Thank you so much.

```
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<div class="slideshow-container">

<!-- Full-width images with number and caption text -->
<div class="mySlides">
    <img class="img" src="https://res.cloudinary.com/mkconsulting/image/upload/v1545204835/sunset1.jpg" style="width:100%">
 <div id="overlay"></div>
 <div class="text">abcde</div>
  <div class="indicator">
  <button class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></button> 
  <button class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></button> </div>
  </div>

 <div class="mySlides">
<img class="img" src="https://res.cloudinary.com/mkconsulting/image/upload/v1545204834/sunset2.jpg" style="width:100%">
<div id="overlay"></div>
<div class="text text1">abcde</div>
     <div class="indicator">
     <button class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></button> 
     <button class="dot1" onclick="currentSlide()"></button> </div>
</div>

 <!-- Next and previous buttons -->
 <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
  <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
</div>
 </html>

  <style>
 .slideshow-container {
 max-width: 100%;
position: relative;
padding-top:30px;
margin: auto;
height:auto;
   }

    .img{
 height:350px;
```

}

```
    .mySlides {
   display: none;
     }

   .prev, .next {
   cursor: pointer;
   position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
 width: auto;
 margin-top: -22px;
padding: 16px;
color: white;
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 18px;
transition: 0.6s ease;
border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
user-select: none;
 z-index: 2;
  }

  .next {
 right: 0;
 border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
  }

 .prev:hover, .next:hover {
      background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
      }


  .text {
 color: #f2f2f2;
font-size: 20px;
padding: 8px 12px;
 position: absolute;
bottom: 8px;
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
top:45%;
 font-family:'cwTeXYen';
  z-index: 2;
     }

.text1 {
color: #f2f2f2;
font-size: 40px;
  top:35%;
    }

.text2 {
font-family:'Noto Sans TC';
color: black;
font-weight:300;
}

.indicator {
color: #f2f2f2;
font-size: 15px;
padding: 8px 12px;
position: absolute;
bottom: 8px;
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
top:85%;
}

.dot {
cursor: pointer;
height: 15px;
width: 15px;
margin: 0 2px;
background-color: transparent;
border-radius: 50%;
transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
 border: 1px solid #ffffff;

}

.active, .dot:hover {
background-color: #ffffff;
}

.dot1{
height: 15px;
width: 15px;
background color:white;
border-radius: 50%;
 border: 1px solid #ffffff;
 margin-left: 2px;
}

#overlay {
position: absolute; 
height:50%;
top: 30%; 
left: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5); /* Black background with opacity */
z-index: 1;
}
</style>

<script>
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);


function plusSlides(n) {
showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
var i;
var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1} 
if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
  slides[i].style.display = "none"; 
  }
for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
  dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
 }
 slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block"; 
dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
}
</script>
```

Comment: you need to include w3.css in the html head:    `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css"> `  as shown in https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/default.asp

Comment: ahh i copied this code from jsfiddle, so i think missing the w3.css is not a main issue? coz if it is, all css features wont function properly (not only the dot issue im encountering), right?

anyway, to make the question clearer, i added the link back

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how about this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<title>W3.CSS</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<style>
    .mySlides {
        display: none
    }

    .w3-left, .w3-right, .w3-badge {
        cursor: pointer
    }

    .w3-badge {
        height: 13px;
        width: 13px;
        padding: 0
    }

    .w3-display-container {
        position: relative;
    }

    .myCaptions {
        position: absolute;
        top: 40%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        padding: 0.5rem 2rem;
        background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    }
</style>
<body>

<div class="w3-content w3-display-container" style="max-width:800px; text-align: center">
    <p class="myCaptions" style="display: none;">Mountains</p>
    <p class="myCaptions" style="display: none;">Nature Wide</p>
    <p class="myCaptions" style="display: none;">Snow Wide</p>
    <img class="mySlides" src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_mountains_wide.jpg" style="width:100%" alt="image1">
    <img class="mySlides" src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_nature_wide.jpg" style="width:100%" alt="image2">
    <img class="mySlides" src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_snow_wide.jpg" style="width:100%" alt="image3">
    <div class="w3-center w3-container w3-section w3-large w3-text-white w3-display-bottommiddle" style="width:100%">
        <div class="w3-left w3-hover-text-khaki" onclick="plusDivs(-1)">&#10094;</div>
        <div class="w3-right w3-hover-text-khaki" onclick="plusDivs(1)">&#10095;</div>
        <span class="w3-badge demo w3-border w3-transparent w3-hover-white" onclick="currentDiv(1)"></span>
        <span class="w3-badge demo w3-border w3-transparent w3-hover-white" onclick="currentDiv(2)"></span>
        <span class="w3-badge demo w3-border w3-transparent w3-hover-white" onclick="currentDiv(3)"></span>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    let slideIndex = 1
    showDivs(slideIndex)

    function plusDivs (n) {
        showDivs(slideIndex += n)
    }

    function currentDiv (n) {
        showDivs(slideIndex = n)
    }

    function showDivs (n) {
        let i
        const x = document.getElementsByClassName('mySlides')
        const dots = document.getElementsByClassName('demo')
        if (n > x.length) {
            slideIndex = 1
        }
        if (n < 1) {
            slideIndex = x.length
        }
        for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            x[i].style.display = 'none'
        }
        for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
            dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(' w3-white', '')
        }
        x[slideIndex - 1].style.display = 'block'
        dots[slideIndex - 1].className += ' w3-white'

        // adjust captions
        const captions = document.getElementsByClassName('myCaptions')
        for (i = 0; i < captions.length; i++) {
            captions[i].style.display = 'none'
        }

        captions[slideIndex-1].style.display = 'block'
    }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: emmm what about the dots below? I can manage the slideshow thing, but the dots are the problem. I've added a new image to my question, the part circled in blue is my main concern and i want my slideshow banner to look exactly like the one on the image.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is it possible to add text caption on top? The code worked perfectly without the caption, but it collapsed when i tried to add text caption.

Comment: @Charlottekpc By "on top" you mean in the middle of the image or on top of entire carousel ?

Comment: checkout the new edit with caption on top of everything

Comment: By "on top" i mean the text overlaying the image (just like the part circled in red in image 2 newly added to the question)

Comment: @Charlottekpc Check out the latest snippet.

Comment: Thank you sooo much, you're amazing!!